# How to resolve transitive spring bean dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a project with 3 maven modules as follows:

```
main
|
|--extern
|   |
|   |-Adapter.java
|   
|--business
    |-- CustomerService.java
```

- *business* is included as a dependency in *extern*
- *business* and *extern* both are included as a dependency in *main*
- *main* module has the @SpringBootApplication class

Here are the signatures of these classes:

**MainApplication**

```
package com.company.main;

@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.business", "com.company.extern"})
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Running the service...");
        var applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
        var customerService = applicationContext.getBean("customerService"); //able to access the bean here
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
package com.company.extern;

@Component
public class Adapter.java implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowire
    CustomerService customerService; //this is null
    
    public void expose(){
        customerService.serve();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        var service = context.getBean("customerService"); //able to access bean here
    }
}
```

**CustomerService**

```
package com.company.business;

@Service
public class CustomerService {

    public void serve() {
        log.info("serve");
    }
}
```

I can't get Spring to wire `customerService` bean in `Adapter.java`. what am I missing here? How can I make it work?

Comment: I assume that's supposed to be `@Autowired` not `@Autowire`?  The `extern` import is also missing a semicolon.